# time complexity for comparing two strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How is the running time of the ff function `o(nlogn)`?

```
function isPermutation(a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return a.split("").sort().join() === b.split("").sort().join();
}
```

aren't you checking the length of both strings, or is it dependent on the implementation of sort?

Comment: Who told you this was *O(log n)*?

Comment: http://geniuscarrier.com/is-permutation-javascript/

Comment: It would be `O(n log n)`, not `O(log n)`. The length check just gives an early out so in the (possibly common) case of mismatched lengths, you can avoid the `O(n log n)` work.

Comment: @devdropper87 That says *O(n log n)*.

Comment: The sorting (`.sort()`) it self is at `O(n log n)` for average and best cases. So there is no way this could be `O(log n)`.

Comment: Whoops - reading helps. I still don't see how that is o(n log n). it seems to depend on implementation of sort and the built-ins of javascript

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the sort algorithm: http://bigocheatsheet.com/#sorting

Comment: For each letter in string one you have to check if it is also on string two. So this obviously will be O(N*N) but you can use sorting(quick-sort) to sort the string chars first and then compare them serially. which will give you O(n*logn)

Comment: @DegenSharew add it as an answer and I'll select it :)

Comment: okay if that helped you. :-)

Comment: quicksort is `O(n^2)` in worst case, isn't it?

Comment: We are talking about average running time of sorting algorithms in general. But in my example I mentioned quicksort which is still valid I think, its worst case might be O(n^2) but its average is still O(n\*logn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to definition of [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), *a String is permutate of another String if and only if all chars in the first String are also in the second String.*

**Example**: `"answer"` is permutate of `"awerns"`.

So to write an algorithm that checks if one string is permutate of another string all you have to do is:

1. Check if length of the two strings is same, return false if they are not same.
2. For each letter in String one check if it also exists in String two.

The above algorithm's running time will be [image: O(n*n)] but you can use sorting to solve same problem:

1. Check if length of two strings is same, return false if they are not same.
2. Sort the two strings
3. Each char in the Strings sequentially, like  `stringOne[i] == stringTwo[i]`

So in this one if you use good sorting algorithm like [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) the overall running time will be [image: O(n*logn)]

Comment: Splitting the string has `O(n)` complexity which is also important for the calculation although it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Yeah exactly, but as you said it the running time still remains O(n\*logn)

Comment: Big-O describes the worst case. In case of quick sort it has to be `O(n^2)`

Comment: @Andreas Actually that is a common misconception, see [this cs exchange answer here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case).